# usort returning unpredicable results

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting, usort

I have an array of objects returned from a database. A print_r on the unsorted array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 53162
            [title] => Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Standee
            [path] => node/53162
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 64185
            [title] => Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Stanchion Sign
            [path] => node/64185
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 52190
            [title] => Betty Crocker Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Shipper
            [path] => node/52190
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 53159
            [title] => Frito-Lay Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Packaging
            [path] => node/53159
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 53164
            [title] => Nabisco Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Violator
            [path] => node/53164
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 52607
            [title] => Doritos Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Packaging
            [path] => node/52607
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 52720
            [title] => Kroger Big K Cola &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Packaging
            [path] => node/52720
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 52729
            [title] => Windex Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Packaging
            [path] => node/52729
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 52731
            [title] => Ziploc Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Packaging
            [path] => node/52731
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 53157
            [title] => Stacy&#039;s Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Cut Cases
            [path] => node/53157
        )

)
```

I want to sort the array by the nid property, so I used a custom usort function (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122062/sort-multidimensional-array-of-objects).)

```
function my_search_sort($a, $b) {
  strcmp($a->nid, $b->nid);
}
```

I called it like this:

```
usort($docs, 'my_search_sort');
```

and then did another print_r. The results look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 52720
            [title] => Kroger Big K Cola &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Packaging
            [path] => node/52720
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 52729
            [title] => Windex Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Packaging
            [path] => node/52729
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 52731
            [title] => Ziploc Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Packaging
            [path] => node/52731
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 53157
            [title] => Stacy&#039;s Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Cut Cases
            [path] => node/53157
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 52607
            [title] => Doritos Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Packaging
            [path] => node/52607
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 53164
            [title] => Nabisco Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Violator
            [path] => node/53164
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 64185
            [title] => Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Stanchion Sign
            [path] => node/64185
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 52190
            [title] => Betty Crocker Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Shipper
            [path] => node/52190
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 53159
            [title] => Frito-Lay Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Packaging
            [path] => node/53159
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 53162
            [title] => Kroger &#039;Giving Hope&#039; Standee
            [path] => node/53162
        )

)
```

It's obviously doing *something*, but it's not sorting in ascending order according to nid. What do I need to do to get that to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your custom sort function needs to return the value:

```
function my_search_sort($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a->nid, $b->nid);
}
```

**EDIT**
I've updated the code on the [other answer you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122062/sort-multidimensional-array-of-objects), it was incorrect.