# Sort multidimensional array of objects

Tags: php, sorting, object, multidimensional-array

I have seen so many example at stackoverflow to sort multidimensional array of object like

[Sort array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122062/sort-array-of-objects)

[Sort array of objects by object fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields)

But none them could help me to sort my multidimensional array of objects given below

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [request] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [address] => test
            [citystatezip] => New York
        )

    [message] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [text] => Request successfully processed
            [code] => 0
        )

    [response] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [results] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [result] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [zpid] => 27965224
                                    [links] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [homedetails] => test
                                            [graphsanddata] =>test
                                            [mapthishome] => test
                                            [comparables] => test
                                        )

                                    [address] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [street] => test
                                            [zipcode] => test
                                            [city] => test
                                            [state] => NY
                                            [latitude] => 29.802114
                                            [longitude] => -95.504244
                                        )

                                    [zestimate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [amount] => 342911
                                            [last-updated] => 11/27/2014
                                            [oneWeekChange] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [deprecated] => true
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [valueChange] => 5766
                                            [valuationRange] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [low] => 312049
                                                    [high] => 373773
                                                )

                                            [percentile] => 0
                                        )
                                    [rentzestimate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [amount] => 5177
                                            [last-updated] => 11/24/2014
                                            [oneWeekChange] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [deprecated] => true
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [valueChange] => 370
                                            [valuationRange] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [low] => 3417
                                                    [high] => 7041
                                                )

                                        )
                                    [localRealEstate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [region] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 271582
                                                            [type] => neighborhood
                                                            [name] => test
                                                        )

                                                    [links] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [overview] => test
                                                            [forSaleByOwner] => test
                                                            [forSale] => test
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                ..............................
                                ..............................
                        )                            
                )
        )
)
```

I need to sort the above array on the basis of key **amount** in descending order. But the problem is amount key exist under two different parent keys "zestimate" and "rentzestimate".

i have tried the following function but it did not work:

```
public function my_comparison($a, $b) {
    if ($a->amount == $b->amount) {
            return 0;
    }
    return ($a->amount < $b->amount) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify please: you want to sort an array `response->results->result`?

Comment: Please provide an example of your result based upon the supplied input example.

Comment: The stated problem does not have a general solution. You should decide how you want to sort elements with contradicting amounts (say, `ze=>1,rze=>10` vs `ze=>5,rze=>5`.)

Comment: Yes, i want to sort response->results->result. I just have given example of Zeroth object of array and rest at are at the end.

Comment: Then, as @mudasobwa noticed, you have to decide how both `amount` fields influence the final result, i.e. the sum of these fields is used as a value for comparing two elements in the `result` array. Do you know this criteria?

Comment: I actually want to sort response->results->result array on the basis of response->results->result->zestimate->amount value. This amount does not have to do anything with response->results->result->rentzestimate->amount.

Answer (score 2):

`response->results->result` is an array of `SimpleXMLElement` objects. You want to sort the array based on the inner `zestimate->amount` property of the element in descending order.

You have to write a comparison function that accepts `SimpleXMLElement` objects and, because you want a descending order, returns `1` if the `zestimate->amount` property of the first object is less than that of the second, `-1` if it's greater and `0` if it's equal:

```
public function my_comparison(SimpleXMLElement $a, SimpleXMLElement $b) {
    if ($a->zestimate->amount == $b->zestimate->amount) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->zestimate->amount < $b->zestimate->amount) ? 1 : -1; // note the signs
}
```

Comment: how would it sort the entire array in desecding order on the basis of zestimate->amount

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify it. Pay special attention to the signs of the result of `my_comparison` function.